# Vue onclick event returns wrong srcElement

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, dom-events

Why is it that `onclick` event returns wrong `srcElement` even if I have put the `onclick` on the parent element it still return child element as the source of the click event. How can I make it to always select the element where I put the `onclick` method? Below is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 player-column" v-for="(player, index) in group" v-on:click="selectPlayers" :data-image="player.image">
    <div class="players">
        <div class="player-image">
            <div class="circle">
                <img class="img-responsive" v-if="player.image" :src="player.image | alternateIfImageExists(player.teamName, player.firstName+' '+player.familyName, 'small')">
                <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" v-else></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="player-info">
            <p class="player-fullname">{{player.firstName}} {{player.familyName}}</p>
            <p>{{player.playingPosition}}</p>
            <p v-if="player.teamCode !== ''">{{player.teamCode}}</p>
            <p v-if="player.teamCode == ''">{{player.teamName}}</p>
            <img :src="player.team_logo" :alt="player.teamCode">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Vue method**

```
selectPlayers(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

**Console logs:**

```
currentTarget:null
srcElement:div.player-info
target:div.player-info

currentTarget:null
srcElement:img.img-responsive
target:img.img-responsive
```

Comment: [Read this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2236#issuecomment-274737003) for the explanation why `currentTarget:null` in `console.log`, when in fact it is not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By adding `this` as parameter when calling method I'm able to get the source of the element was

```
v-on:click="selectPlayers(this)"
```

**Method:**

```
selectPlayers(e) {
   console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `currentTarget`.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a @mouseover="mouseover"><img src="" /></a>
  </div>
</template>


<script type="text/javascript">
  export default {
    name: 'component',
    methods: {
      mouseover(e) {
        //e.currentTarget will always return a
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- **target, srcElement** is the element that triggered the event (e.g., the user
  clicked on)
- **currentTarget** is the element that the event listener is attached to.